# Regex force length of specific regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm using R and need a regex for

> a block of **N** characters starting with zero or more
>   whitespaces and continuing with one or more digits afterwards

For **N** = 9 here are

**examples of valid strings**

- `123456789`
- `kfasdf  3456789asdf`
- `a        1`

and **examples of invalid strings**

- `12345 789`
- `1       9`
- `a     678a`

Comment: Why is the last one invalid?

Comment: @d.b Sorry, I corrected my formulation a little. There should be digits only (after the whitespace). The block in the last one either begins with non-whitespace/non-digit or ends on a non-digit.

Comment: Why is the second one valid then?

Comment: @d.b Because We have a block of length 9. The first two characters in the block are spaces, the remaining seven characters are the string `3456789` (consisting of digits only at least one digit).

Comment: There is, of course, `\d{9}|\s\d{8}|\s{2}\d{7}|...|\s{8}\d`, unless I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: What if input string is ` 123456789` (3 spaces followed by 9 digits) - should it match ` 123456` (3 spaces followed by 6 numbers) ?

Comment: ...and what if input string is `1234567890` and `N = 9`, should it match `123456789` or `234567890` ?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to match 8 times either a digit OR a space not preceded by a digit and then match a digit at the end.

```
(?<![\d\h])(?>\d|(?<!\d)\h){8}\d
```

*In parts*

- `(?<![\d\h])` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a horizontal whitespace char or digit
- `(?>` Atomic group (no backtracking)

  - `\d` Match a digit
  - `|` Or
  - `\h(?<!\d\h)` Match a horizontal whitespace char asserting that it is not preceded by a digit
- `){8}` Close the group and repeat 8 times
- `\d` Match the last digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6P6MI/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/sdRSch)

Example code, using *perl=TRUE*

```
x <- "123456789
kfasdf  3456789asdf
a        1

12345 789
1       9
a     678a"
    regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<![\\d\\h])(?>\\d|(?<!\\d)\\h){8}\\d", x, perl=TRUE))
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "123456789" "  3456789" "        1"
```

If there can not be a digit present after matching the last 9th digit, you could end the pattern with a negative lookahead asserting not a digit.

```
(?<![\d\h])(?>\d|(?<!\d)\h){8}\d(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qz1cd/1)

If there can not be any digits on any side:

```
 (?<!\d)(?>\d|(?<!\d)\h){8}\d(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mtGB7T/1)

Answer (score 1):

Using string `s` from @d.b's answer.

Extract optional whitespace followed by numbers.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(s, '(\\s+)?\\d+')
#[1] "123456789" "  3456789" "        1" "12345"     "1"         "     678"
```

Check their length using `nchar`.

```
nchar(str_extract(s, '(\\s+)?\\d+')) == 9
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Using the same logic in base R function.

```
nchar(regmatches(s, regexpr('(\\s+)?\\d+', s))) == 9
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

If there could be multiple such instances we can use `str_extract_all` :

```
sapply(str_extract_all(s, '(\\s+)?\\d+'), function(x) any(nchar(x) == 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

***Basic form:***  space bias
this is a basic form that has no anchors or boundrys

`(?:[ ]|\d(?![ ])){8}\d`

[dem0](https://regex101.com/r/rS05bf/1)

feature:

- block of 9
- minimum block size of 2
- match takes maximum spaces vs minimal digits

---

***Basic form:*** number bias
same basic form that has been modified to get number bias.

`(?=((?:[ ]|\d(?![ ])){8}\d(?!\d)|\d{9}))\1`

[dem1](https://regex101.com/r/aEiR2p/1)

feature:

- block of 9
- minimum block size of 2
- match takes minimal spaces vs maximum digits

---

End of line ***Anchor method*** (numeric bias) :

`(?=[ ]{0,8}?\d{1,9}(.*)$)[ \d]{9}(?=\1$)`

[dem2](https://regex101.com/r/doHs1H/1)

feature:

- block of 9
- minimum block size of 2
- match takes minimal spaces vs maximum digits
- single capture is not part of match
- line orientated regex, needs `multi-line option` if string is more than 1 line

Comment: Why did you changed your original answer? It looked nice. Wanted to upvote. Did I miss some error in it?

Comment: the original had too restrictive boundry conditions `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)`. Better to not have boundry at all

Comment: yes but boundary constraints are not clear from the question. So you can just keep both versions in your answer. Anyway thanx for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

The desired substring contains 9 digits or fewer than 9 digits. In the second case it begins with a space, ends with a digit and each of the 7 characters in between is a space preceded by a space or a digit followed by a digit. We therefore could use the following regular expression.

```
\d{9}|\s(?:(?<=\s)\s|\d(?=\d)){7}\d
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P9wNDC/1/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\d{9}       : match 9 digits  
|           : or
\s          : match a space
(?:         : begin non-capture group
  (?<=\s)   : next character must be preceded by a space
  \s        : match a space
  |         : or
  \d        : match a digit
  (?=\d)    : next character must be a digit
)           : end non-capture group
{7}         : execute non-capture group 7 times
\d          : match a digit
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a comma before the spaces
2. split at the comma
3. keep only either space or digits
4. Count number of characters and see if it matches the required size

```
s = c("123456789", "kfasdf  3456789asdf",
      "a        1", "12345 789", "1       9",
      "a     678a")

sapply(strsplit(gsub("(\\s+)", ",\\1", s), ","), function(x) {
    any(nchar(gsub("[A-Za-z]", "", x)) == 9)
})
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/7IlxOa/2)

```
[ \d](?:(?<=[ ])[ ]|\d){7}\d
```

and in **R** use

```
str_extract(x, regex('[ \\d](?:(?<=[ ])[ ]|\\d){7}\\d'))
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/tWIouq).

---

[image]

*Please note that in the above regex pattern the `[ ]` may be replaced by a simple space character. Using `[ ]` is a common practice to increase readability.*

Answer (score -1):

That's not an easy task for regexp-s. You really should consider parsing the string yourself. At least partially. Because you need the lengths of capturing groups and regexp-s do not have this feature.

But if you really want to use them, then there's a workaround:
<sub>I'll use JS so that the code can be ran right here.</sub>

```js
const re = /^(.*)(\s*\d+)(.*)$(?<=\1.{9}\3)/

console.log(re.test("123456789"))
console.log(re.test("kfasdf  3456789asdf"))
console.log(re.test("a        1"))

console.log(re.test("12345 789"))
console.log(re.test("1       9" ))
console.log(re.test("a     678a"))
```

where

1. `\s*\d+` meets your base condition of zero or more spaces followed by one or more digits
2. we can't get groups' lengths, but we can get everything before and after the main group. That is what `^(.*)` and `(.*)$` are for.
3. Now we need to check that all three groups add up to a full string, for that we use look behind assertion `(?<=\1.{9}\3)` and we set the desired `N` for a number of symbols allowed in the main group (9 in this case)

You didn't mention how the regexp should behave in all situations, for example in this one:

```
"         3456780000000"
```

with extra spaces and extra digits.
So I won't try to guess. But it's easy to fix the regexp I've provided for all your cases.

**Update:**

I think the Edward's [**original** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62226300/12610347) is the best for you (look in the history). But not sure about boundary constraints. They are not clear from your question.

But I'll still leave mine because, while Edward's answer is shortest and fastest for your specific case, mine is more general and better suits the **title of the question**.

And I added performance tests:

```js
const chars = Array(1000000)
const half_len = chars.length/2
chars.fill("a", 0, half_len)
chars.fill("1", half_len, half_len + 9)
chars.fill("a", half_len + 9)
const str = chars.join("")
function test(name, re) {
  console.log(name)
  console.time(re.toString())
  const res = re.test(str)
  console.timeEnd(re.toString())
  console.log("res",res)
}
test("Edward's original", /((?<!\d)\s|\d){9}(?<=\d)/)
test("Ωmega's"          , /(?=[ \d]{9}(.*$))[ ]*\d+\1$/)
test("Edward's modified", /(?=[ ]{0,8}?\d{1,9}(.*))[ \d]{9}(?=\1$)/)
test("mine"             , /^(.*)(\s*\d+)(.*)$(?<=\1.{9}\3)/)
```

Surely lookbehinds are not cheap!

Comment: I see using Chrome or something with latest ECMA-262. Your regex worked on my ipad with Chrome, but on my Firefox lookbehinds aren't supported. Have to wonder how this segment works `^(?=\1.{9}\3)` since it is not in a quantified loop and groups 1 and 3 are not yet and never will be initialized at this point, probably equivalent to `^(?=.{9})`. Could test it by adding the dollar `^(?=\1.{9}\3$)`, but not supposed to work. In the other regex, `(?<=\1.{9}\3)` constitutes a variable width lookbehind, seemingly a Dot-Net feature indeed (be carefull with this feature).

Comment: @Edward, thanx you've open my eyes on FF. But there is tag "R", and with "perl=TRUE" flag lookbehinds should work. About lookaheads - yes, my mistake.

Comment: if lookbehind supported still none are variable length until dot-net and now ECMA-262. R wont support this nor perl last i check (but maybe). Seems counter intuitive that a backref inside a lookbehind constitutes variable width but it does only support by some i think

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a clean **regex** solution, then you should use the following pattern:

```
(?=[ \\d]{9}(.*$))[ ]*\\d+\\1$
```

...where you combine a positive lookahead with a regular matching that includes a match from the lookahead.

The **R** syntax is then

```
str_extract(x, regex('(?=[ \\d]{9}(.*$))[ ]*\\d+\\1$'))
```

and you can test this code [here](https://ideone.com/20Q11B).

---

If your desire is also to catch a matching N-character long substring, then use

```
str_match(x, regex('(?=[ \\d]{9}(.*$))([ ]*\\d+)\\1$')) [,3]
```

as shown in [this demo](https://ideone.com/7JeBU1).